# Is there a way to show a picture based on cell criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking to show a smiley face if a cell value is above a certain number? Is this possible? Thanks for any help you can provide. Not sure if this is something that would need to be done based on scripting or can be done in excel normally.

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .Range("A1").Value = 88 Then 'Woot Woot'
        .Shapes("Picture_Smiley").Visible = True
    Else
        .Shapes("Picture_Smiley").Visible = False
    End If
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I had added in the code I had written.

Comment: More specifically is there a way to dictate exactly where to put the image?

Comment: See [this page](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/2/4/aligning-shape-objects-with-vba-code) for aligning the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a separate cell just add some kind of formula: =IF("A1" > 10, "J", ""). If the cell is formatted as 'Wingdings' font then it shows as a smiley face

Answer (score 0):

Found it can be done conditionally right in the cell value itself.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Show-images-conditionally/m-p/72589#M952